# how to calculate total using module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program:

```
import display
a = int(input('1st number:'))
b = int(input('2nd number:'))
c = a + b
display.display1
```

and the other with the name 'display':

```
def display1():
    print(c)
```

It will come out :

```
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

how do I define the 'c' to find the total for a and b?. Thanks

Comment: Note to self: the canonical duplicate here addresses the opposite problem (getting the information *out* of the function, rather than *in*). I will need to write an artificial canonical for this, probably. Although this is still not a good signpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter c to the function display1.

So your display1 function should be like as follows

```
def display1(c):
    print(c)
```

And while calling you need to give c to display1 function as a parameter as follows

```
display.display1(c)
```

Comment: thanks for the help...works

Answer (score 1):

```
import display
a = int(input('1st number:'))
b = int(input('2nd number:'))
c = a + b
display.display1(c)
```

.

```
def display1(c):
    print(c)
```